# Correct usage of $.ajaxComplete and $.ajaxError?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery

I've been using the following snippet on my ajax form submits:

```
$.ajax({
url: "",
data: ilmoittautumisdata,
type: "POST",
success:function(){

});
error:function(){

});
});
```

However, I remember that I was told to stop using success and error within it, as they're deprecated (?) and instead use  `$.ajaxComplete();` and  `$.ajaxError();`.

However, reading the docs isn't helping me as I want to use both of them, and this isn't working for me.

```
$('#ilmoittuminen').submit(function(){
            var ilmoittautumisdata = $('#ilmoittuminen').serialize();
            $.ajax({
                //url: "",
                data: ilmoittautumisdata,
                type: "POST"
                });
            $.ajaxComplete(
            function(){
            $('#ilmoittuminen').slideUp();
            });
            $.ajaxError(
            function(){

            });
    return false;
    });​
```

How I should do it?

http://jsfiddle.net/D7qgd/

Comment: Mmmm...you sure is `$.ajaxComplete` and not `.ajaxComplete`. I see this http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/

Comment: oh. How should I do it? @elclanrs

Comment: Where you read it, .ajaxComplete and .ajaxError is global event handle for ajax. Those function is called every ajaxrequest

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Firstly, the word you're looking for is "deprecated". As far as I'm aware, the `success` and `error` properties are definitely *not* deprecated. You can (and should, in your case) continue to use them.

The problem with your attempt to use `ajaxError` and `ajaxComplete` is that they are implemented as *instance* methods, rather than static methods on the jQuery object itself. For that reason, you need to select some element and call the methods on that collection. The element itself doesn't matter at all:

```
$("#someElement").ajaxComplete(function () {
    // Do stuff
});
```

The next problem, which you haven't come across yet, is that the `ajaxError` and related methods register *global* AJAX event handlers. Each time you call one of those methods, you add a new event handler to the global set, and every time an AJAX event is fired, *all* of your registered handlers will be executed.

---

**Update** (Thanks @DCoder)

Looks like the `success` and `error` properties *are deprecated* as of jQuery 1.8. Instead, you can use the `fail`, `done` and `always` methods of the jQuery modified XHR object. Any objects that inherit from the [deferred object](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/) can use these methods (the jqXHR object is one of these):

```
$.ajax(ajaxSetupObject).done(function () {
    // Handle success
}).error(function () {
    // Handle error
});
```

Comment: [*Deprecation Notice: The jqXHR.success(), jqXHR.error(), and jqXHR.complete() callbacks will be deprecated in jQuery 1.8. To prepare your code for their eventual removal, use jqXHR.done(), jqXHR.fail(), and jqXHR.always() instead.*](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)

Comment: @DCoder: Thx for that, I didn't know and I just finished working on some code that uses success and error, damn

Answer (score 1):

This code handles a success and error inside the ajax method.if there is a success it prints out success, with the object you receive, and vica versa.

```
$.ajax({
   type: 'json',
   url: 'foobar.com',
   success: function(s) { 
     console.log('success' + s);
   },
   error: function(e) {
     console.log('error' + e);
   }
});
```

Comment: Code only answers are not encouraged, can you add some commentary?